# Magento 2.1.9 checkout page getting error in console network

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I am using wegbshop Matrix shipping method after login customer group I am facing this issue in checkout page when place order

```
{message: "Please specify a shipping method.",…}
message: "Please specify a shipping method."
trace: "
#0 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(18811, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#1 /home/apps2/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(18811, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#3 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#5 /home/apps2/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#8 /home/apps2/public_html/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#9 {main}"
```

Comment: Make sure your shipping method is active from backend or else check any extension is not hiding it via plugin or observer.

Comment: my shipping method active on backend side